# Kentico Cloud Custom ContentLinkUrlResolver circular dependency on DeliveryClient

Tags: kentico-kontent

I'm trying to upgrade the my Kentico Cloud SDK from v7 to v10. Before I was just creating a new instance of the DeliveryClient to build a service of my site's urls to resolve and then pass that to my CustomContentLinkUrlResolver e.g.

```
services.AddSingleton<NavigationProvider>(c => new NavigationProvider(new DeliveryClient(deliveryOptions) {
    CodeFirstModelProvider = { TypeProvider = new CustomTypeProvider() }
}, cache));

services.AddSingleton<IDeliveryClient>(c => new CachedDeliveryClient(projectOptions, cache)
{
    CodeFirstModelProvider = { TypeProvider = new CustomTypeProvider() },
    ContentLinkUrlResolver = new CustomContentLinkUrlResolver(c.GetRequiredService<NavigationProvider>())
});
```

So I have this circular dependency where the DeliveryClient depends on the CustomContentLinkUrlResolver which depends on the DeliveryClient.

The frustrating part is the ResolveLinkUrl(ContentLink link) method doesn't have the information I need to resolve urls, because the urls are defined by the taxonomy of an item which is unavailable in ContentLink which means I have to do another lookup of the item to get the taxonomy.

I don't know how to get around CustomContentLinkUrlResolver having a dependency on DeliveryClient.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got your situation right:

You call `DeliveryClient` instantiated as a singleton in dependency injection container and this client is using `CustomContentLinkUrlResolver` which needs to make another API call to get information to the item taxonomy, but you want to use a different instance of `DeliveryClient` to avoid circular dependency on the singleton implementation.

In that case, it is possible to create a new instance of `DeliveryClient` by using [`DeliveryClientBuilder`](https://github.com/Kentico/delivery-sdk-net#using-the-deliveryclient) introduced in [version 8](https://github.com/Kentico/delivery-sdk-net/releases/tag/8.0.0).

```
// Sample resolver implementation
public class CustomContentLinkUrlResolver : IContentLinkUrlResolver
{
    public string ResolveLinkUrl(ContentLink link)
    {
        IDeliveryClient client = DeliveryClientBuilder.WithProjectId("<YOUR_PROJECT_ID>").Build();
       // Do the call
       // return URL
    }
}
```